# Unable to mock class method on CLLocationManager using OCMock with iOS7

Tags: ios, xcode, ocmock

I'm trying to write an XCTest (iOS7, XCode5) together with OCMock.

I've got a class which implements the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol, and has a property which is an instance of a CLLocationManager. (I supply the instance of the CLLocationManager to the my initialiser method, so that I can inject it at runtime or test).

When testing the delegate class, I create a mock CLLocationManager.

In a test, I want to achieve something like this:

```
[[[[mockLocationManager stub] classMethod] andReturnValue:kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied] authorizationStatus];
result = [delegateUnderTest doMethod];
//Do asserts on result etc etc
```

The problem is, XCode is complaining about my code.

```
test.m:79:68: Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSValue *' is disallowed with ARC
test.m:79:68: Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'int' to parameter of type 'NSValue *'
```

kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied is an int I understand (as defined in a TypeDef). 
So, I can't use

```
[[[[mockLocationManager stub] classMethod] andReturn:kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied] authorizationStatus];
```

which would expect an object ('andReturn' is an 'id').

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to box the value in an `NSValue` instance, and not pass the primitive value itself. For example:

```
[[[mockLocationManager stub] andReturnValue:@(kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)] authorizationStatus];
```

The above makes use of the Objective-C literal syntax for `NSNumber`s. Also, I omitted the `classMethod` call above `CLLocationManager` doesn't have an instance method `authorizationStatus`.

More support for this can be found on the the [OCMock website](http://ocmock.org/features/):

> If the method returns a primitive type then andReturnValue: must be used with a value argument. It is not possible to pass primitive types directly.

That's also what the compiler error is telling you - that you are passing an `int` instead of an `NSValue` instance.

Comment: Thanks. Done the trick. I had tried @kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied (without the brackets), which seemed to be the right thing. Those extra brackets, @(kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied), sorted me out.